# How to trigger smart text selection without delay

Tags: react-native-webview

I am writing an app for fast markup of webpages.  I want the user to be able to touch text in the webview and not have to wait for the little handlebars to pop up to expand the text selection.  They press the words and immediately the handlebars show up, probably with the selection in the collapsed state.

In other words, I want touching the screen to immediately trigger a smart selection:

[image]

Is it possible?  I've looked around everywhere.  It doesn't look like React Native has a way to change it, and I can't find any HTML/DOM/web methods to do it either.

I have two motivations for wanting to do this, and am open to alternative suggestions:

1. I want the user to have visual feedback about where the caret is, so they can place it to perform certain actions that only work when the selection is collapsed and in a certain location (i.e., inside a word).
2. I don't want them to have to wait to expand their text selection.  The latency for smart selection in my use case is way to high, but I still want the smart selection.